# Whats the latest bash version that can be ran on RHEL3?

Tags: bash, vulnerability

I have an older RHEL 3 server that I can't upgrade at the moment. Its running

```
GNU bash, version 2.05b.0(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Yum is broken. My concern is shellshock. Would this:

```
bash-4.3.43-3.fc26.i686.rpm
```

from the rpmfind site work on my system? If not what are my options to update bash? Epel repos only go back to epel5.

Comment: You could always compile from source, but I guess your gcc is also ancient (or absent).

Comment: I'm thinking I'd have more luck finding a compatible rpm.

Comment: `bash-4.4` compiles just fine on a Knoppix LiveCD 3.2 from 2003. I can't see why it wouldn't work on your RHEL3

Comment: I'd strongly suggest upgrade as RHEL3 does not contain any of the latest security patches and thus it would be a very vulnerable system if put on the internet in general.

Comment: Who down-voted this? Its a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Per Stephane's comment, is a compiler available, or are you stuck installing RPMs?

Answer (score 2):

You should download bash 2.05b with the rpm src by example, and patch it with the last patches for 2.05b, make a new rpm in bash with the specs, test it on a platform and install it.

Red Hat doesn't maintain this distribution RHEL3, but you can make your own bash package rpm and update your bash version with gnu update...

bash205b-013    :

05/Oct/2014 00:00      2.7 KB       bash205b-013
05/Oct/2014 00:00      72 B     bash205b-013.sig

ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/